# Need help fixing a Laravel PageController class error

Tags: laravel

Whenever I try to click a button on localhost site such as the manage users
I get the error:

> Target class
> [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PagesController] does
> not exist.

I tried a lot of different things to try fix it and I  just don't know how to fix it. I asked on forums like this too and I none of the suggestions I was given helped.

Here is the code for my page **controller**:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\WorkWithPage;
use App\Models\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('admin');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->isAdminOrUser()) {
            $pages = Page::paginate(5);
        } else {
            $pages = Auth::user()->pages()->paginate(5);
        }
        return view('admin.pages.index', ['pages' => $pages]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('admin.pages.create')->with(['model' => new Page()]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(WorkWithPage $request)
    {
        //
        Auth::user()->pages()->save(new Page($request->only([
            'title','url','content'])));

        return redirect()->route('pages.index')->with('status', 'The page has been created.');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Page  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Page $page)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->cant('update', $page)) {
            return redirect()->route('pages.index');
        }

        return view('admin.pages.edit', ['model' => $page]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Page  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(WorkWithPage $request, Page $page)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->cant('update', $page)) {
            return redirect()->route('pages.index');
        }
        $page->fill($request->only([
            'title','url','content']));

        $page->save();
        return redirect()->route('pages.index')->with('status', 'The page has been updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Page  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Page $page)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->cant('delete', $page)) {
            return redirect()->route('pages.index');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my **web.php** route:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/admin', function() {
    return view('admin.index');
})->middleware('admin');

Route::resource('/admin/pages', \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PagesController::class, ['except' => [
    'show'
]]);

Route::resource('/admin/users', \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UsersController::class, ['except' => [
    'create','store','show'
]]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: I just need to find out how to stop it from duplicating the App\Http\Controllers part and looking for it twice

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into your the `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file and comment this line:

```php
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
//should be
//protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

If you do so, you'll be able to use this notation your are using when declaring your routes:

```php
Route::get('something', [\Fully\Qualified\Namespace::class, 'method']);
```

**However, these kind of routes, will not work anymore:**

```php
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

// since there are no more default namespace, you must use 
// Route::get('/home', '\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index');
// or 
// Route::get('/home', [\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index']);
```

You have to choose which route declaration style you use and stick to it for all routes.

Nowadays, `Route::get('something', [\Fully\Qualified\Namespace::class, 'method'])` is what you should use.

Comment: I just tried adding this, not sure if im adding it wrong or if it's something else but the same error comes up. But if i make the '\\' single instead of double and remove the quotes it comes up with a total different error

Comment: Apologies i'm a beginner with laravel

Comment: No problem everybody was a beginner at some point! I assure you this is the answer you are looking for, I can reproduce your exact same problem on my side. Just remove all other routes, only keep those that are needed, used the same notation everywhere.

Comment: If you don't uncomment the line in the `RouteServiceProvider.php` file, then all your routes have their namespace prefixed by `\App\Http\Controllers`. Since you also use this namespace when declaring your route, you are getting these weird double `\App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageController` things.

Comment: Just one question, what version of Laravel are you using? It matters since some things changed in Laravel 8.

Answer (score 0):

Add the controllers at the beginning of your `web.php` routes file

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PagesController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UsersController;
```

Then define your route as

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('pages', PagesController::class);
    Route::resource('users', UsersController::class);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is because you forgot to put `[]` when calling your controller.

Modify this:

```
Route::resource('/admin/pages', \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PagesController::class, ['except' => [
    'show'
]]);
Route::resource('/admin/users', \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UsersController::class, ['except' => [
    'create','store','show'
]]);
```

by:

```
Route::resource('/admin/pages', [\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PagesController::class], ['except' => [
        'show'
    ]]);
Route::resource('/admin/users', [\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UsersController::class], ['except' => [
            'create','store','show'
        ]]);
```